# select multiple double side

Tags: java, jsp, select, struts

i want to do a select multiple double side 
like this : http://www.senamion.com/blog/jmultiselect2side.html  (Demo2)
but i don't know how i can retrieve my data when i click submit button..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, assuming your select has the name "secondSelect[]" as per the demo page, the two generated selects will have the names "secondSelectms2side__sx" and "secondSelectms2side__dx"

So it is these names you should be looking for in the request object